# Formatting an array to order by specified unix timestamp in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which has a timestamp consistently on [3] ( an example of the array data below)

I would like the array to be sorted using the timestamp. I've seen a few stackoverflow posts that apparently do this using two methods, `array_multisort()` and `usort()` but I've been unable to replicate either.
Here is what I've tried based on my own code:

**Attempt 1** - I pass the array to usort, then attempt to take it apart with the foreach.  Applying this method definitely changes the order of the results, but the dates seems to be no specific order (ascending, descending).

```
function sortArray($a1, $a2){
    if ($a1[3] == $a2[3]) return 0;
    return ($a1[3] > $a2[3]) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($the_array, "sortArray");

foreach($the_array as $sh) {
    $uid = $sh['uid'];
    $username = $sh['username'];
    $datetime = $sh['datetime'];
    $type = $sh['type'];

echo "<p> $uid , $username, $datetime, $type </p>";
}
```

**Attempt 2** - tried using array_multisor() which again gives me results in a different order but I don't understand what it is sorting by exactly.

```
foreach ($the_array as $key => $node) {
   $timestamps[$key]    = $node[3];
}
array_multisort($timestamps, SORT_ASC, $the_array);
//process the array with a foreach to show results
```

**My theory** here is that it isn't properly processing the unix timestamp and I'm not sure what I can do about that.  Is it smart to take out all the characters of the timestamp so it is a simple line of numbers ( 2014-01-02 03:02:12 becomes  20140102030212 )? Or is there another way to process it with the timestamp in it's current form?

Here is an example of the data in the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 20013
            [0] => 20013
            [username] => myhipswontlie
            [1] => myhipswontlie
            [rating] => 4.00
            [2] => 4.00
            [datetime] => 2014-01-27 23:40:56
            [3] => 2014-01-27 23:40:56
            [type] => rated
            [4] => rated
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 20025
            [0] => 20025
            [username] => brasilchika
            [1] => brasilchika
            [rating] => 4.00
            [2] => 4.00
            [datetime] => 2014-01-02 03:02:12
            [3] => 2014-01-02 03:02:12
            [type] => rated
            [4] => rated
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 10002
            [0] => 10002
            [username] => crtten
            [1] => crtten
            [datetime] => 2014-01-25 01:33:34
            [2] => 2014-01-25 01:33:34
            [type] => visits
            [3] => visits
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is your numeric keys don't seem to match up in your arrays. Sometimes the datetime is found in the 3rd key, sometime it is found in the second key (which is odd considering they look like they come from `mysql_fetch_array()` which will make uniform arrays).

To solve this you should use the associative array key instead:

```
function sortArray($a1, $a2){
    if ($a1['datetime'] == $a2['datetime']) return 0;
    return ($a1['datetime'] > $a2['datetime']) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($the_array, "sortArray");
```

Comment: Ahh I didn't even notice that was switching on me. I realize now what is happening, some of the results have a rating coming through which was shifting the key.  Thank you very much.